# Selecting unique values of keys inside postgresql json field

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, postgresql

I have the following model:

```
Shipment:
  reference_numbers: [] :json field
```

reference fields general structure is as follows:

```
[{'reference_field_name': 'freight_number', 'reference_field_value': '0098'}, {'reference_field_name': 'bill_of_lading', 'reference_field_value': '1190' }]
```

Here the field name can vary from delivery to delivery. It can be anything not just bill_of_lading and freight_number.

What is the best way to find all unique values of 'reference_field_name' across reference_numbers across Shipments?

Comment: Are u looking for a query to do it? I don't think it can be done in activerecord. You'll have to fire a sql query . other option is do it in ruby, which may be slower.

Comment: @Joel_Blum Yes an sql query. I tried to get it to work, but never gets the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know, it's a bit late for answer but for thouse of you who have similar task, there is some cool postgresql features :)

First, let's unnest reference_numbers into table:

```
select jsonb_array_elements("reference_numbers") as fields from shipment
```

This will return a rowset with one column, each row will have one item from all reference_numbers arrays. So, if you have two shipment rows and each one have two items in reference_numbers field, than this query will return 4 items.

Second, let's select distinct fields:

```
with fields_rowset as (
    select 
        jsonb_array_elements("reference_numbers") as fields 
    from shipment
)
select DISTINCT fields->'reference_field_name' from fields_rowset
```

Note, i've used jsonb_* function but if you have json field you have to use json_* alternative.

Comment: I finally ended up with the following sql https://gist.github.com/midhunkrishna/077984da65c1307ff60a57cc10e0fae5

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT DISTINCT(jsonb_object_keys(outputs)) FROM shipment;
```